# How do I check User Role before Logging in A user with Spatie's Laravel-Permission?

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication, laravel-permission

I'm using Spatie's "Laravel Permission" Package for the ACL. Everything is working perfectly. I now want to allow only the User roles 2 and 3 to Login.

Previously, before using "Laravel Permission" package I had only this "role" column on my table and I could easily Log In a user with this line of code on Login Controller's credentials method.

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
$credentials = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
//$credentials['role'] = '1';
return $credentials;
}
```

```
$credentials = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
$credentials['role'] = '1';
```

How do I allow Login only for the 2 and 3 User Roles?

Comment: Have you tried with a middleware ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with the workaround as follow:

If you're using the default `LoginController` from the `App\Http\Controllers\Auth` folder, then override its `attemptLogin()` method that comes from the Trait used.

```php
    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        if( $this->guard()->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
        ) ) { // Credential auth was successful
            // Get user model
            $user = Auth::user();
            return $user->hasRole([2, 3]); // Check if user has role ids 2 or 3
        }

        return false;
    }
```

`hasRoles()` method comes from the `HasRoles` trait used for the `User` model.

Comment: Thanks ☺, the same applies for role names `return $user->hasRole(['admin', 'stack overflower']);`

Answer (score 2):

You can override authenticated() in LoginController and check user role. Pretty simple.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    //Check user role, if it is not admin then logout
    if(!$user->hasRole(['Admin', 'Super-Admin']))
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        return redirect('/login')->withErrors('You are unauthorized to login');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could override the Laravel credentials during login. In your default `LoginController` from the `App\Http\Controllers\Auth` folder, then override its credentials(`Request $request`) method that comes from the Trait used.

Override it to look something similar to this

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{

 return [ 'email' => $request-> { this-> username() }, 'password' -> $request -> password, 'role_id'  => [ '1', '2' ] ];
```

This is presuming you have a `role_id` in your user model. Worked for me.return